# javascript taking bit longer to execute

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, for-in-loop

I am trying to achieve send sms whenever google spreadsheet gets updated with mobile no. but its taking too long to execute, surely I am making any mistake but can't find out the one. Requesting your help. below is my script.

```
function denver() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"));
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:M1000");
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (i in data) {
        var rowData = data[i];
        var contactx = rowData[5];
        var textx = rowData[8];
        var Decision = rowData[12];
        var EMAIL_STATUS = rowData[28];

        var messages_url = "https://49.50.67.32/smsapi/httpapi.jsp? 
        username = maruti & password = maruti123 & from = MARUTI & to = " + contactx + " & text = " + 
        textx + "&coding=0&flash=2";
        var options = {
            "method": "post",
        };

        options.headers = {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("maruti:MARUTI")
        };

        UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in the Google Sheets? Also, which do you need range of that size (A2:M1000) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. there are 1000 rows I need to use. the size will be (A2:M1000)

Comment: Can you check how long each of this `messages_url` request takes time? That might be what makes your program takes longer to execute

Comment: I have checked the same if I reduce the size then its taking smaller time to execute.

Comment: So, this `UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);` statement takes no time to execute?

Comment: Yes. but I have same data size in another application and its working fine.

Comment: If you aren't rate limited by this external API, consider using `UrlFetchApp#fetchAll` (it is asynchronous) in batches. Consult documentation. Also, combining `for .. in..` enumeration with arrays that should be *iterated* is not recommended. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

You're using a for loop over a section of the spreadsheet that seems very large, A2:M1000, and seem to be performing a number of memory accesses on each interation, similar with in. Iterating over data can be very time consuming and very likely negatively affects your run time, I'd be hesitant to use a for loop over a large data set. Fetch will also increase your run time as it takes longer to retrieve the information you're asking for. If I were you I would break this into separate functions that look at more specific ranges